# Is it possible to import excel data into Gephi?

Tags: excel, gephi

I am trying to import Excel data into Gephi, but the file formats it supports are of  CSV. Is there any way of importing excel data into Gephi

Comment: Why don't you save the excel file as CSV from Excel or OpenOffice Calc and then import?

Comment: Forgot to mention that there is a spigot that might be what you are looking for. Check [here](https://marketplace.gephi.org/plugin/excel-csv-converter-to-network/)